# Crop image to square once it's captured with GPUImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage in a project that makes use of storyboards.

To display a GPUImageView without black borders to the user and then automatically crop the picture once it s taken in a 320x320 square, is that accurate enough to frame the GPUImageView to 320x427 (320*4:3, 427 thus being the rounded value of 426.666..) and then apply a crop filter

```
 GPUImageCropFilter *filter = [[GPUImageCropFilter alloc] initWithCropRegion:CGRectMake(0.0, 52.0/427.0, 1.0, 51.0/427.0)];
```

Thus cropping 52px up and 51px down to get the 320x320 square.

Are there any ways to be more accurate on these calculations without using hard coded values?

Thx